# Apache cordova issue in Netbeans 7.4

Tags: java, apache, netbeans, cordova

I just downloaded Netbeans 7.4 and I am trying to explore Apache Cordova.
When I try to create a new project, I get always BUILD FAILED problem.

Here is the log

```
ant -f /Users/jason/NetBeansProjects/HTML5Application/nbproject "-Dupdate.task.jar=/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.4.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/webcommon/ant/extra/org-netbeans-modules-cordova-projectupdate.jar" "-Dios.provisioning.profile=/Users/jason/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/6B14AF63-D435-47F0-AF54-F24E2066EEBA.mobileprovision" -Dandroid.project.activity=HTML5Application "-Dios.certificate.name=iPhone Developer" -Denv.DISPLAY=:0.0 -Dsite.root=www_nb_temp "-Dcordova.version=3.1.0-0.2.0
"upgrade-to-cordova-project
check-cordova-project:
check-cordova-version:
upgrade-to-cordova-project:
cordova -d create . com.coolappz.HTML5Application HTML5Application
Error: Path already exists and is not empty: /Users/jason/NetBeansProjects/HTML5ApplicationCreating a new cordova project with name "HTML5Application" and id "com.coolappz.HTML5Application" at location  "/Users/jason/NetBeansProjects/HTML5Application"

at CLI.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/create.js:63:25)
at new CLI (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/cli.js:105:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:41:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:901:3
/Users/jason/NetBeansProjects/HTML5Application/nbproject/build.xml:78: exec returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

I have already node.js installed (version v0.10.20) and Apache Cordova (3.1.0-0.2.0)

What is the solution? It is a bug ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually I got the problem is not a Netbeans bug, it is an Apache Cordova bug at the version **3.1.0-0.2.0** (Latest until now).

The solution is to downgrade from the version **3.1.0-0.2.0** to **3.1.0-0.1.0** and everything will work fine:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g cordova
sudo npm install -g cordova@3.1.0-0.1.0
```

Thank you @Geertjan & @Cocorico for your help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to name your app to see what appens :

```
cordova -d create "HTML5Application" com.coolappz.HTML5Application HTML5Application
```

Also, check all environment variables (ant,java,...) even if it seems to be good :

```
java --version
...
```

Try to change the folder name and app name and come back here to tell what happened.

Comment: The same issue if I try to create with different names. The installed java version : 1.7.0_17

Comment: and ant --version and adb --version ?

Comment: and did you have some space caracter in your path ? because it doesnt work if you have space in path !